# No Module Named AppKit

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, appkit, python-playsound

I am trying to run an audio file in Python:

```
from playsound import playsound

def main():
    playsound('audio.mp3')

main()
```

However, I keep getting the following error:

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/playsound.py", line 55, in _playsoundOSX
from AppKit     import NSSound
ImportError: No module named 'AppKit'
```

I am using Python 3.5.4 on macOS 10.12.6. I have tried installing it via pip but I am returned this error:

```
Using cached AppKit-0.2.8.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: flask in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from appkit)
Collecting pygobject (from appkit)
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pygobject (from appkit) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pygobject (from appkit)
```

Comment: Looks like you forgot to install `pyobjc`...

Comment: @Lukas I installed pyobjc; still getting the same error.  Pyobjc was installed to the Python 2.x directory. I'm using Python 3

Answer (score 37):

If you want to use AppKit you have to install PyObjC:

```
pip3 install -U PyObjC
```

or

```
pip install -U PyObjC
```

Answer (score 3):

If anybody else stumbles upon this error when using this library, trying to do exactly as @user5124826 first stated in the question, as long as you have you have done a:

> pip3 install AppKit

or

> pip install AppKit

And also installed PyObjC...Wherever you have your packages installed, for example, pip when used with virtualenv will generally install packages in the path

> virtualenv_name>/lib//site-packages.

Look for the AppKit package, and it will most likely be in all LOWERCASE. So it would be appkit. Just change this folder to 'AppKit', and you should be good to go

Comment: Same problem for me (suddenly, probably after some brew updates etc.).
However, if I rename as suggested I'm not getting `AttributeError: module 'AppKit' has no attribute 'NSWorkspace'`

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same problem (suddenly, probaby after some system upgrade of brew, etc.).

I solved it by reinstalling from scratch, following iTerm's docs.

```
pip uninstall appkit
pip uninstall iterm2
pip list | grep pyobjc | cut -d ' ' -f 1 | xargs pip uninstall -y
```

then, depending on your system

```
pyenv rehash
```

then reinstall only iterm2

```
pip install iterm2
```

According to the docs, `iterm2` has `pyobjc` as a dependency and it all provides `AppKit`, so no additional installation needed.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it works only in Python 2.7. Because Python 3 requires small letters, in import appkit you get the error.

I have updated a library to work with small caps import: https://github.com/TinKurbatoff/appkit