# While installing AppKit, command errored out with exit status 1. How can I resolve this?

Tags: python, macos, appkit, cairo, pycairo

I'm working on a folder cleaning project and was trying to install AppKit using the command:

```
> pip3 install appkit
```

However, I received a series of error messages. The first error was:

```
>  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
```

Full Error Message:

https://pastebin.com/zxDSMzMy

I'm using Python 3.9 running on macOS 11.0.1

How can I fix this problem and install AppKit?

Comment: Is it [this library](https://github.com/nitipit/appkit)? It seems it only supports Gnome desktops. There's [an issue](https://github.com/nitipit/appkit/issues/33) from 2019 there but not much else. However, I also found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47281564/14316282) on Stack Overflow, maybe you can try it out.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I found the solution in that page, but in a different answer. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67669847/8339501)

Answer (score 1):

The problem was resolved for me after **uninstalling** `pyobjc` and **installing** `iterm2` (which includes both `pyobjc` and `AppKit`).

Explanation in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67669847/8339501).